# Хостинг и как его самим создать

Tags: hosting

У меня вопрос такой есть. Есть сайты/корпорации продают хостинг потом домейн так далее.Как могу я на своем компютере создать такой хостинг сервер чтобы я сам как бы сделал себе домейн и хостинг. Что потребуется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Концептуально вам нужно лишь:

1. Установить какой-нить веб-сервер (nginx, apache и т.п.).
2. В зависимости от того, хотите ли вы, чтоб это работало лишь локально, или из сети тоже.

   - Если локально, то в `/etc/hosts` (на Windows это `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) прописать `127.0.0.1  mysite.com`. Теперь при открытии `mysite.com` на своём компьютере, будет открываться ваш сайт, который вы настроили в nginx. (или другом веб-сервере). Так же поддомены настроить и т.п.
   - Если нужен доступ из вне.

     1. Завести статичный внешний ip.
     2. Завести статичный локальный ip (настроить DHCP).
     3. Купить домен. Настроить его DNS (`A` и `CNAME` записи на ваш внешний ip).
     4. Настроить проброску портов на роутере.
     5. Теперь вы можете у себя локально, добавляя записи в настройки `nginx`, создавать поддомены к своем купленному домену `mysite.com`.

Если вопрос про выдачу/продажу доменов первого уровня со своего компьютера, то не получится такое. Можно лишь настроить работу поддоменов своего купленного домена.